# Calibration parameters for FLIR Blackfly cameras?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, flir, spinnaker-cam

I am currently doing a project with a FLIR Blackfly camera (BFS-U3-120S4C to be exact), and have not been getting a low enough reprojection error in my calibration experiments.

I know that manufacturers often have the intrinsic parameters and distortion coefficients available, and FLIR has a Spinnaker Python API to operate their cameras and they advertise them as Machine Vision cameras, so I strongly suspected that this would be the case for them.

However, I have not been successful in finding this in my Google searches. Does anyone know of FLIR have given out the values for these parameters somewhere?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: since you can mount any lens, you'll have to calibrate yourself for your specific lens.

Comment: It hasn't been my experience that intrinsic and distortion coefficients are "available" from manufacturers since they are very much a product of the camera and optics pairing. May I ask how you are calibrating? I'd highly recommend the OpenCV libraries. My experience of poor calibrations has been insufficient input images or not enough density on the reference grid. Ensure your calibration images are varied and cover the entire FOV between them.